# Not able to use a variable inside Find command in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, variables, find

I have a string s which contains `"subham$"`

Now using excel's built in command find i like to know the position of the dollar symbol,there might be other ways but i like to use find in vba code and use a variable inside it

```
Sub testfind()
    Dim s As String
    s = "subham$"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=FIND(""$""," & s & ")"
End Sub
```

I am getting the error Application defined or object defined error,
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I can't actually fathom what you're trying to do with the code, or why you'd be doing it, but in order to solve your problem:

You're not wrapping the string of `s` in quotes. Try:

```
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=FIND(""$"",""" & s & """)"
```